# How to open a pcap file with Wireshark scapy?

Tags: python-3.x, wireshark, scapy

I've written a python V3 script that sniffs 10 packages, write a log and opens the log in Wireshark. But somehow it keeps opening an empty log in /tmp

My code:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
from scapy.all import *
x = sniff(count=10)
wrpcap('log', x, append=False)

wireshark('log')
```

The output:

```sh
WARNING: No route found for IPv6 destination :: (no default route?). This affects only IPv6
WARNING: PcapWriter: unknown LL type for str. Using type 1 (Ethernet)
ERROR: 'str' object has no attribute 'sent_time'
ERROR: 'str' object has no attribute 'sent_time'
ERROR: 'str' object has no attribute 'sent_time'
ERROR: 'str' object has no attribute 'sent_time'
ERROR: 'str' object has no attribute 'sent_time'
ERROR: 'str' object has no attribute 'sent_time'
ERROR: 'str' object has no attribute 'sent_time'
ERROR: 'str' object has no attribute 'sent_time'
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
```

It should open the log instead of the variable but I can't figure out how.

The scapy documentation (https://readthedocs.org/projects/scapy/downloads/pdf/latest/) says:

> With a filename (passed as a string), this loads the given file in Wireshark. This needs to be in a
>   format that Wireshark supports.

Does anyone know how to open a pcap log in Wireshark?

Comment: Hmm, that does look weird. Which version of scapy are you using? Make sure it's the latest.

Comment: I would change the name to `log.pcap` so that it has an extension.

Comment: @RossJacobs changing the name to `log.pcap` gives the same result. Scapy writes the log automatically as a .pcap file.

Comment: @Cukic0d I'm using the newest version of python3-scapy (0.23-1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the method wireshark() by CTRL + click on `wireshark('log')`.

```py
def wireshark(pktlist, *args):
    """Run wireshark on a list of packets"""
    fname = get_temp_file()
    wrpcap(fname, pktlist)
    subprocess.Popen([conf.prog.wireshark, "-r", fname] + list(args))
```

It seems that it does always create a temp file because the method expects to receive a list of variables and then opens the temp file.

I could fix it by using `subprocess.Popen([conf.prog.wireshark, "-r", fname] + list(args)` directly in my code instead of using ´wireshark('log')´.

The working code:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
from scapy.all import *

x = sniff(count=10)
wrpcap('log', x, append=False)

subprocess.Popen([conf.prog.wireshark, "-r", 'log'])
```